# Page is not top aligned when we redirect to it from another page

Tags: html, css, redirect

When I click on a button to redirect to a new page, new page is not at the top position. I have to scroll down to have a look. Please have a look at below pictures.[image]

Page titled 'LIST' is the page I am redirecting to.

**HTML of the page I'm redirecting to is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Some Title</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.mobileMenu').click(function(){
                $("#mobileNav").toggle();
            });
            $("#mobileNav li").click(function(){
                $('#mobileNav').hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="innerheader">
        <div class="innerwrapper">
            <h1 id="someId" onClick="location.href='index.html'"></h1>
            <div class="mobileMenu"></div>
            <div id="mainNav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">xxx</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">xxx</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">xxx</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="mobileNav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">xxx</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">xxx</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#xxx">xxx</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="priceList">
        <h4>List</h4>
        <div class="innerwrapper">
            <div class="leftsection">
                <div class="listSec">
                    <h5>ABC</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p>A</p>
                            <span>70</span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <p>B)</p>
                            <span>300</span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>C</p>
                            <span>100/150/200</span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**The CSS**

```
.innerwrapper { 
    width:1140px; 
    height:700px !important; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    position:relative; 
    z-index:99999
}

#priceList{ 
    background:#fff; 
    padding-bottom:80px;
}
#priceList h4{
    font-size:24px;
    color:#37444d;
    line-height:65px; 
    font-weight:300;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    border-bottom:solid 1px #f0f0f0;
    border-top:solid 1px #f0f0f0;
}
```

If I remove height from above class, it works fine.

Comment: FYI: your missing a closing `;` on your z-index (not sure if that is just a typo)

Comment: Technically a semicolon isn't needed after the last css property although it is good practice to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `#priceList` div is being pushed down is because your div `innerwrapper`has `height: 700px` set to it which pushes the content beneath it(i.e. priceList) down 700 pixels.

Edit:

To solve this you need to remove/change `height: 700px !important` on `innerwrapper`.

If it's crucial for your design that `innerwrapper` is 700 pixels high you have two options. Either absolute position your price list and place it exactly where you want it **or** you can move your pricelist to within the innerWrapper.

Comment: What else do you want me to provide?

Comment: The CSS for the rest of the elements that's relevant to the issue. e.g. priceList. Is priceList supposed to be inside of the innerWrapper or after it?

Comment: I have edited my question with css for price list. No other class I find relevant to the issue. priceList is supposed to be outside innerwrapper.

Comment: Okay. Looking at your CSS for PriceList I'm going to refer you back to my original answer. I edited it to clarify how you can solve this.

Answer (score -1):

Your script is doing something here.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.mobileMenu').click(function(){
            $("#mobileNav").toggle();
        });
        $("#mobileNav li").click(function(){
            $('#mobileNav').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Try removing the script part and see how it works. Then, you can recode it as per the need.

Comment: I tried removing it. Script is not causing the problem. It has something to do with z-index. Unable to figure out exact cause :(